# ReactNative with Stripe Google Pay

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments, google-pay, react-native-google-pay

We have implemented the stripe google-pay payment using in reactNative code. My code working fine with sandbox account but live environment suppose to not working. We followed this link:
[enter link description here](https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=react-native)

**My code**:

```
await confirmPlatformPayPayment(
            response.data.client_secret, // ClientSecret key from PaymentIntent response
            {
              googlePay: {
            testEnv: true,
            merchantCountryCode: 'US',
            merchantName: 'xyz',
            currencyCode: 'USD',
            billingAddressConfig: {
              format: PlatformPay.BillingAddressFormat.Min,
              isPhoneNumberRequired: true,
              isRequired: true,
            },
            isEmailRequired: true,
            }})
```

We are using front end reactNative and backend for PHP for paymentIntent create. When we execute the google pay checkout then we received following error

**Error:**

*{"stripeErrorCode":null,"message":"Google Pay failed with error:","declineCode":null,"type":null,"localizedMessage":"Google Pay failed with error:","code":"Failed"}*

Could you please help us resolved the issue?

Comment: If your code works in Stripe's test mode then your code is probably not the issue.  Can you find more details about the failure in your logs and/or in Stripe's Dashboard and update your question with those details?  You should also try with a few different Android devices and different cards and update your question with the results of those tests.

Comment: Thanks @JustinMichael. We will check different android devices. But we only face stripe error such as Google pay failed with error